# Restricting pages among users in asp .net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having problems with restricting the certain services(pages) to anonymous users.I want to only allow home page to any user who doesn't log-in yet.when the users are logged-in then they will have the permission to use some services.

in my web.config file i added following code;

```
<location path="">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"></deny>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

<location path="Content">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"></allow>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

<location path="Scripts">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"></allow>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>


<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="~/Home"></forms>
</authentication>


</system.web>
```

but when i run the project it will give the following error;

Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Account/Login

i don't have a controller called Account.I used "no authentication" mood when i started the project.Is that a problem???

Comment: Umm... yeah. That's a problem.

Comment: I'd look into the 'Authorize' and 'AllowAnonymous' class/method attributes.